# Visual Studio 2022 Debugger IISExpress

Tags: c++, .net, dll, mfc, visual-studio-2022

We have a Visual Studio 2022 solution that uses .NET 6 including a MVC web project. After I added a C++ with MFC DLL to the solution I got the error message below when trying to debug the web project. The web project has not been changed and does not interact with the C++ DLL. The debugger is using IISExpress. The project will launch with IISExpress without using the debugger from VS2022. Also,

I've had 2 other developers pull my branch and they both can run everything without error. A repair of the VS2022 install didn't help. Something is wrong with my environment, not the code, but I'm at a loss at what to delete or reset.

The deugger outut is 2 lines announcing that the debugger is starting and a breakpoint in Main() does not get hit.

VS2022 shows this error in a message box prevenitn the debgger from starting "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectShim' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHistory'"

I deleted the source and the DLLs, reubild everthing. I ran a repair of the VS2022 install. Neither helped. As mentinoed, 2 other devs can compile and run my branch. I'd like not to reinstall VS2022 which is my last resort.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. Getting A's is far more likely if you ask a Q. What's your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling both VS2022 and IIS to attempt a repair, my coworkers and I deicded that something was corrupted in Winodws. I was the ony dev that saw this problem and found baekernel.dll faults in the event viewer.  I reset my PC and reinstalled everything. The error no longer occurs.